# Jquery DataTable : Replacing the buttons with icons at the same location

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, datatables

I have added the default Excel button in my datatable.

Here's the script for  it :

```
$('#searchResult').DataTable(
     {
         "dom": '<"top"lB>rt<"bottom"ip>',
         buttons: [
         {
             extend: 'excel',
             exportOptions:
             {
                 columns: ':visible'
             }
         },
        'colvis']
)}
```

And I've placed the button at the extreme right(top-side) above the data-table through the following css:

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-buttons {
  float:right; 
}
```

But I have no idea about how can I replace the Buttons with icons ( to improve the UI) while maintaining the same functionality. And how can I insert the icons at the exact same location as of the buttons??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each button is enriched with a unique class - `.buttons-excel` etc, so you can very easy swap the inner content of a certain button with something else. Do this in the `initComplete()` callback. "Icons" can be many things, here an example using [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) :

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
  //...   
  initComplete: function() {
   $('.buttons-copy').html('<i class="fa fa-copy" />')
   $('.buttons-csv').html('<i class="fa fa-file-text-o" />')
   $('.buttons-excel').html('<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" />')
   $('.buttons-pdf').html('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" />')
   $('.buttons-print').html('<i class="fa fa-print" />')
  }

} );
```

produces something like this : [image]

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/6639xcj4/**

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad.One question though - Suppose if I want to change the background-colour of the icon element then how would I do using the above code.

Comment: @Mr.SK, in CSS target `.btn-default` -> **https://jsfiddle.net/6639xcj4/2/** it is tempting to style `i .fa` but it is the button we want to style.

Comment: Oh Ok. Understood. I appreciate your help @davidkonrad

Comment: @Mr.SK, **IMPORTANT** Stupid me. Have to withdraw my comment above :( You must target **`.buttons-html5`** instead. I was wrongly referring to the bootstrap `.btn-default` class, but this would change all other buttons as well. I am so sorry for the mistake. See updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/6639xcj4/5/**

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`buttons.buttons.text`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.text) option to show an icon in the button instead of regular text. Note also that the [`buttons.buttons.titleAttr`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.titleAttr) option is used to specify a tooltip title for the button, which can improve accessibility, letting users know what the button does when they hover their mouse over the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend:    'copyHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'Copy'
            },
            {
                extend:    'excelHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'Excel'
            },
            {
                extend:    'csvHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'CSV'
            },
            {
                extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'PDF'
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/prashantpokhriyal/9ygsx7pw/3)